# Element combinations

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have a list:

```
lis = {"ab", "cde", 2,"rs",3,"tu","v","w",7}
```

and would like to get the following list:

```
lis2 = {abcde, 2,rs, 3,tuvw,7}
```

... with adjacent strings joined and separated by integers.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't mind code that generates messages, then the following will work:

```
Quiet[List@@StringJoin[lis],StringJoin::string]

(* {abcde,2,rs,3,tuvw,7} *)
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
List @@ StringExpression @@ lis
```

> {"abcde", 2, "rs", 3, "tuvw", 7}

In version 10 and later versions you can also use `SequenceCases` with an appropriate pattern:

```
SequenceCases[lis, {a : Except[_String] ..., b__String, c : Except[_String] ...} :> 
  Sequence[a, StringJoin@b, c]]
```

> {"abcde", 2, "rs", 3, "tuvw", 7}

Answer (score 6):

```
lis = {"ab", "cde", 2, "rs", 3, "tu", "v", "w", 7};

lis //. {s___, str1_String, str2_String, f___} :>
  {s, StringJoin[str1, str2], f}

(*  {"abcde", 2, "rs", 3, "tuvw", 7}  *)
```

or

```
lis //. {s___, str1_String, str2_String, f___} :>
  {s, str1 <> str2, f}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit elaborate:

```
If[VectorQ[#, StringQ], StringJoin[#], Sequence @@ #] & /@ SplitBy[lis, StringQ]
   {"abcde", 2, "rs", 3, "tuvw", 7}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SplitBy[lis,NumericQ] /. {{x__String} :> StringJoin[x], {x_?NumericQ} :> x}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {"ab", "cde", 2, "rs", 3, "tu", "v", "w", 7};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
SequenceSplit[list, a : {_Integer} :> a[[1]]] /. {a__String} :> StringJoin[a]
```

{"abcde", 2, "rs", 3, "tuvw", 7}

Answer (score 2):

**Using `SequenceReplace`:**

```
list = {"ab", "cde", 2, "rs", 3, "tu", "v", "w", 7};

SequenceReplace[list, {s__String} :> StringJoin[s]]
```

---

*Result:*

> {"abcde", 2, "rs", 3, "tuvw", 7}

Comment: +1, extremely nice. I didn't know that `SequenceReplace` would automatically skip the integers like this.

Answer (score 1):

If we build `ConsecutiveQ` we can handle the problem as follows:

```
ConsecutiveQ[list_List] := AllTrue[Differences[list], # == 1 &]

p1 = Flatten[Position[list, _String]];
p2 = Complement[Range[Length@list], p1];
pstr = Transpose /@ List /@ SequenceCases[p1, {__}?ConsecutiveQ];
pnum = Transpose /@ List /@ SequenceCases[p2, {__}?ConsecutiveQ];
strs = Extract[list, #] & /@ pstr;
nums = Extract[list, #] & /@ pnum;

Flatten[Riffle[strs, nums] /. s_ /; MatchQ[s, {__?StringQ}] :> StringJoin@s]

(*{"abcde", 2, "rs", 3, "tuvw", 7}*)
```

Or using `Cases` and `SplitBy`:

```
SplitBy[list, StringQ]

Cases[%, s_ :> If[MatchQ[s, {__?StringQ}], StringJoin@s, Splice@s]]

(*{"abcde", 2, "rs", 3, "tuvw", 7}*)
```